# What is the best way to split an Image in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, image

I am looking to split an Image into two tiles. One would be the left half of the image the other the right (so both half the size of the original Image). These will then sit next to each other before an animation will pull them apart.

I have attempted to create two images and used the Clip property. This does show the correct part s of the image but does not rezise the original image so I am left with white space between the image. ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745541/how-does-silverlight-image-clipping-work))

I could use a copy out the pixels into a new image or use an two image brushes and a two rectangle elements. However I was wondering what the best option is and what other people have used?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can look at Pete Blois' example here which kind of does this at a much larger scale

http://blois.us/blog/2009/07/explode.html

but the concepts should be similar.