# How do I create a frame by frame animation on windows phone 7 (silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mobile

What is the best way to create a frame by frame animation composed of png files on windows phone 7 application (silverlight)

This can be easily done in Android using AnimationDrawable and in iOS using UIView animationImages.

Comment: This post will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812752/spritesheet-in-silverlight

Comment: How many frames?  Over what period?  Looping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a storyboard to animate the source property of an Image control, you can find some example code [Candle Tutorial](http://compiledexperience.com/windows-phone-7/tutorials/candle)

Answer (score 3):

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/WP7-Animations.aspx) discusses 4 ways how to do animations:

- Storyboard-based animations created in a) Xaml, b) code
- Per-frame animations
- Timer-based animations

There is no "best way", i.e. the answer depends on your goal. Basically

- Storyboard animations are nicest (highest frame rate), take most CPU cycles (because they make use of a privileged thread), support only primitive property types. You also have to learn respective API that can be used either in Xaml or in the code.
- The other 2 types provide less fluent, but more CPU-effective approach. You have no limitations, but also no support - in other words you have to do everything yourself. (Which is often easier than using the Storyboard language.)