# How to use an image like a sprite sheet with an image class?

Tags: c#, wpf, sprite, sprite-sheet

My research on rendering 2d images led me to this...
[Spritesheet in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812752/spritesheet-in-silverlight)
This Answer was good enough however, I do not want to use rectangle.
I think using an image class to just show the image makes more sense.. After trying to understanding the above example. I came up with following code...

```
img = new Image();
img.Source = 500x500BigHugeImage;
img.Width = 100
img.Height = 100
img.Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.None;
img.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Top;
img.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
```

Now the image class only shows the top left corner of the source image.
I need to navigate through the huge 500x500BigHugeImae in order to move to the
I can't navigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think using an image class to just show the image makes more sense.

You are not just "showing an image", you need a specific portion of it, in that case it does make more sense to use `Rectangle` in combination with an `ImageBrush`.